# Interviewing with same company, different team. How to prevent my previous unsuccessful application at a different team from hurting my chances?

Tags: interviewing, rejection

As mentioned in the title, I have previously interviewed with team A at a company, got to the final stage (where I didn’t perform well) and got a rejection. Now, after some time, I am interviewing with team B within the same company.

I am wondering what to tell team B if they ask whether I have had other applications in this company. Should I tell them that I did and it didn’t work out? I’m worried this could lead them to contacting team A who would potentially pass their (negative) feedback, which may hurt my current application.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: I haven't received feedback, but based on my judgment, I think it's because I handled some typical interview questions with a negative attitude.

Comment: Reaching final stage interview is NOT a bad performance. Lack of hire does not mean you're bad.

Comment: If you are the second best of 100 applicants, that is excellent, but you don’t get hired. In that situation a company might even call you for a new job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have previously interviewed with team A at a company, got to the
> final stage (where I didn’t perform well) and got a rejection. Now,
> after some time, I am interviewing with team B within the same
> company.
>
> I am wondering what to tell team B if they ask whether I have had
> other applications in this company.
>
> I think it's because I handled some typical interview questions with a
> negative attitude.

There's no need to volunteer any information about your previous interviews. If you are asked if you previously interviewed there, be honest and direct. Something like "Yes, I interviewed with Team A, but wasn't selected." would work.

In the unlikely event that Team B asks about why you weren't selected, explain that you don't really know as you weren't given any feedback, but that you feel like you may have inadvertently given off a negative attitude while answering some questions and you feel bad about it.

This time around, make sure you are more careful to consider each interview question separately and give each your best answer with a completely positive attitude every time.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming an even reasonably competent HR department, team B will have known about your application to team A long before they even talk to you.

The absolute, completely worst thing you can do is to lie about it. That would be the end of your chances with that company now and at any point in the future, because nobody wants a liar in their company.